# Non-trivial equalities modulo prime powers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The following problem (modified a bit) appears in Elementary Number Theory by Underwood Dudley:

> Show that for all odd $n\ge 3$, $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)\equiv 1+9n(n-1)/2\pmod{81}$.

I personally solved this problem by making cases (as is done in the solution to this problem on this website). However, a friend showed me a very insightful solution to this problem. The idea was to show induct down $81\to 27\to 9\to 3$. Call the problem statement $S(n)$. When trying to prove the original statement by induction, i.e. showing $S(n)\implies S(n+2)$, this is reduced to a problem $\pmod{27}.$ Then show this new statement by induction, reducing it to a problem $\pmod{9}$, then to $\pmod{3}$. There has to be some fundamental reason why the original problem is true. Are there other identities such as this which are true (exponential = polynomial mod prime power)? Is it always possible to express $a^n\pmod{p^k}$ as a polynomial in $n$?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  If $p$ is prime, $p+2$ probably isn't, so what are you saying?

Comment: @lulu Sorry. I am proving it's true for all odd integers. (The problem only says primes because it is after discussion of perfect numbers which are of the form LHS).

Comment: I suggest editing your post for clarity.  As it stands, what you wrote is not clear at all.

Comment: In any case, if $p$ is now a general odd number and not a prime as you specified in the problem, then your left hand is a simple periodic sequence $\pmod {81}$ so you just need to reconcile it with the right hand.

Comment: @lulu That was my original solution, I was wondering if it was just a coincidence that it's true and if there are other such identities. Edited for clarity

Comment: @ThePhoenix Awesome, I don't know how I didn't realize that. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.